# Cygwin Icon Broken In Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, taskbar

I have a weird issue that kind of drives me nuts. When I open my Cygwin terminal, the icon in the task bar is broken on my left monitor. When I drag it to the monitor on my right it appears as normal. This is also annoying because if I pin Cygwin Terminal to my taskbar and click on it, the terminals do not stack under the Cygwin icon, but instead stack under the broken icon.

> **Broken Stacking**
>
> [image]
>
> **Left Monitor Taskbar**
>
> [image]
>
> **Right Monitor Taskbar**
>
> [image]

I've already tried resetting the icon cache by deleting  `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db`, then ending `explorer.exe` and restarting the process.

I would simply uninstall and reinstall it but I have configured a lot of things for it, and I don't have enough faith in copying the files from `C:\cygwin64` then pasting them back in and have everything magically work again.

If anyone has any ideas, let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem on a newly installed 32-bit Windows-7 Ent machine. I had the Cygwin Terminal pinned to the task bar and got the broken icon whenever a terminal was invoked.  Subsequent terminals stacked under the broken icon.

I right-clicked the pinned icon, right-clicked "Cygwin Terminal", clicked Properties and changed the target from "C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -" to "C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -"

Now there is no broken icon and all terminals invoked stack under the pinned icon.

HTH
Tom Crane

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm also running Windows 7 Enterprise. I'll give this a shot when I get back to work. I've been out sick the past few days.

Comment: it works for me (windows 10), thank you.

Comment: Awesome! It worked like a charm!

Comment: After doing this, I noticed a few odd things such as the `ls` command not working. Did anyone else experience this, or is it just me?