# How to get a Cygwin icon in windows 7 system tray

Tags: windows-7, windows, cygwin

I have a work mate that has Cygwin installed on a windows 7 pc. In the lower right, in the task bar he has a Cygwin icon. He can click on it and it pops up a directory of all the Cygwin programs he has installed.

Does anybody know how he got that? Is it some sort of Cygwin package that I need to install or is it some other group that is putting a wrapper of sorts around the main Cygwin program.

Any knowledge would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be this? http://superuser.com/questions/1002340/cygwin-icon-broken-in-taskbar

Comment: Nope, nothing to do with task bar and everything to do with system tray.

Comment: Why don't you just ask him? Then you can share with us and [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

How to pinpoint any folder.

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-pin-any-folder-windows-7-taskbar

Than is just a mutter of using for a cygwin folder.

Comment: taskbar != system tray